# How to append each word from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

if I have a list containing str like:

```
mylist = ['hello how', 'are', 'you']
```

How could I iterate through `mylist` so that I get:

```
newlist = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

I've tried regularly looping through but it won't work since there are 2 words in a single element of the list that I want to split into their own elements.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would be to join the elements and then split again:

```
mylist = " ".join(['hello how', 'are', 'you']).split()
#['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re
mylist = ['hello how', 'are', 'you']
new_data = [i for b in map(lambda x:re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', x), mylist) for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
mylist = ['hello how', 'are', 'you']
res = []
for i in mylist:
    res += i.split()
print res
```

**Output:**

```
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.chain` and `str.split` with a generator comprehension is one way.

```
from itertools import chain

mylist = ['hello how', 'are', 'you']

res = list(chain(*(x.split(' ') if ' ' in x else [x] for x in mylist)))

['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```